# jQuery - equivalent of change/keyup

Tags: jquery, html

I have some dropdown menus and input text fields. I don't want to use `change` because the input text field would need to lose focus for that to work. And `keyup` would be pointless on a dropdown menu.

Is there something like `change` and `keyup` I can use that would be effective for both inputs and dropdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 different JS events (one for inputs and other for dropdowns) calling a common method or different method as per your requirement. events You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").on("change", function(){ // or select on basis of class
doSomeThing();
});

$("input[type=text]").on("keyup", function(){ // or select on basis of class
doSomeThing();
});
});

function doSomeThing() {
// some action here
}
</script>
```

You can modify the code as per your need, let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually exactly how I had it - I was just curious if there was some event which would work for both.